# Preview a text file before importing

Tags: r

Suppose that I know nothing about a file except for the complete path. How can I print the first few lines of the file to the console with all hidden characters made visible?

`readLines(path)` seems to give a decent preview. I see that the values are tab-separated due to the `\t` and since it's a character vector of length greater than 1, I also assume that the file contains `\n` (newline) characters.

Are there better was to preview a file such that the newline characters would be shown explicitly and also any other hidden characters like spaces would be replaced with a visible symbol?

```
> readLines(path)
# Warning message: incomplete final line found on 'data/hotdogs.txt'
# [1] "Beef\t186\t495"    "Beef\t181\t477"    "Beef\t176\t425"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
readChar("./sample.txt", file.info("./sample.txt")$size)
```

This will display tabs and newlines , but not white space .